# Can you make newline characters \n display as breaks <br />?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

I'm trying to display emails with IMAP. When the email is text though, the newlines \n don't display properly. I'd rather not convert them to breaks < br /> because if the user wanted to reply to that email, it would now be in HTML instead of plain text. Is there perhaps a javascript function that could display it as a line break without changing the code?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

How about HTML/CSS? If you put your text inside a `<pre>` tag, it will show all newlines exactly as they were. Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect by applying the CSS style `white-space:pre` to any element.

Don't forget to HTMLencode it still (`<` to `&lt;` etc.), otherwise it will all break apart at the first angle bracket.

Comment: You can also add

    word-break: break-word;

to retain automatic line breaks when lines are too long.

Comment: Even better : use `white-space: pre-wrap;` for automatic line break

Answer (score 24):

Just add this `white-space` css style property to render Multiline texts :

```
.multiline
{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

and then :

```
<div class="multiline">
  my
  multiline
  text
</div>
```

now **newlines** will render like br elements.

Comment: Best answer for me, I could use with react on Material Ui Typography component.

Comment: all this time? ALL THIS TIME??!!!! and me who've been converting them to <br> forever...

Answer (score 5):

white-space CSS works fine but for cross-browser compatibility

```
.abc {
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* Modern browsers */
}
```

Your Html

```
<div class="abc">
 Lorem 
 Ipsum 
 is 
 simply 
 dummy
</div>
```

[MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)