# string that contains new line appears without new line in webapi

Tags: angular, typescript, newline

I'm using `angular 8` (client side) and `webapi` (server side)

I'm trying to save string with \n.

When I print the string using console log the string looks OK but when I get the string in `http post` using `webapi` the string appears without \n.

Here is the string that I'm trying to save:

```
summary: string = `בוצעה בדיקת שיניים\n ממצאים:\n רובד על השיניים\nכתמים לבנים/חומים על השיניים`;
```

in console log looks perfect:

> :בוצעה בדיקת שיניים
>
> ממצאים:
>
> רובד על השיניים
>
> כתמים לבנים/חומים על השיניים

but in webapi appears without new line

> בוצעה בדיקת שינייםממצאים:רובד על השיניים כתמים לבנים/חומים על השיניים

I tried to change the string from literal object to simple string, no changes.

So I tried to replace or add \r instead of \n, same behavior.

in the `webapi` the method is:

```
        [ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GenerateReferralsFromEntities")]
        public IHttpActionResult GenerateReferralsFromEntities(string summary)
        {
            using (MBEntitiesContainer context = new MBEntitiesContainer())
            {
                context.P_GenerateReferralsFromEntities(summary);
            }

            return Ok(true);
        }
```

The only way that I was able to do that is to insert a word like 'Enter' into the original string instead of \n and replace the 'Enter' with `Enviroment.NewLine` in my `POST` function. 
This way it works but I prefer a better way to do that.

any Idea?

Thanks for any response!

Comment: Try encoding the \n:
‘\n’ = 10 = 0x0A = line feed
‘\r’ = 13 = 0x0D = carriage return

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553912/2358409

Comment: What http client are you using?  Show the request code.

Comment: hi, @uminber this is not what I needs. The problem is not on my div, in html its display correctly, the problem is when send it as a request.

Comment: added sample of the post function, thanks, @themikeinnyc

Comment: Why is your *webapi* function is an `[HttpGet]` and your client is sending a *post* to server?

Comment: because I am using stored procedure